# Javascript window.onload function not firing on new linked file

Tags: javascript, onload

I have a dual language website and I wanted to toggle the href in the language link. When visitors first visit the site, it loads the 'index.php' file. In the HEAD section of this file it calls a javascript file which has the following code:

```
window.onload = function() {

  var eng = document.getElementById("lang");
  var fn = location.pathname.substring(1)
  if (fn.match("En.php")) {
      eng.href = "index.php";
  } else {
      eng.href = "indexEn.php";
  }
}
```

The 'index.php' file it has an 'a' link element with a blank href (#) with an id of 'lang' which is the link to the English php file. When I click that link it loads the IndexEn.php file just as the js code dictates.

The indexEn.php also has the call to the same javascript in the HEAD section and has the same 'a' link with the same id but the onload function doesnt run so it doesnt set the correct href. I have tested this with an alert in the onload function which doesnt display when indexEn.php loads. I thought the onload function fired each time you called a file or have I misunderstood?

Comment: Yep, the onload should run each time. That is if you have a page refresh. There must be something in the code on your `indexEn.php` page that stops your code from executing. Have a look in your console to see if you have an error.

Comment: you've misunderstood.

Comment: putvande I dont understand what you mean by page refresh. The index.php has a link to the english version of the page. All the HTML and css on the english page is exactly the same as the index.php page but the text is in english,

Answer (score -1):

Sounds like you really just need this to happen when the document is ready.

Try this jQuery.

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    var eng = $("#lang");
    var fn = document.location.pathname.substring(1);
    if (fn.match("En.php")) { 
        eng.attr('href', "index.php"); 
    } else { 
        eng.attr('href', "indexEn.php");
    }
});
```

The non-jquery code.  Put at the bottom of the page so that you can use the document selectors.

```
    var eng = document.getElementById("lang");
    var fn = document.location.pathname.substring(1);
    if (fn.match("En.php")) { 
        eng.href = "index.php"; 
    } else { 
        eng.href = "indexEn.php";
    }
```

Comment: Is there a non jquery version?

Comment: I put in the above code and it doesnt appear to work at all.

Comment: @Lembasts, I added a non-jquery way.  Please put at the bottom of the page.

Comment: its the same as my code - is it the windows.onload function definition that is causing the problem?

Comment: Both Windows onload and document onload happen when that piece is fully loaded (so basically the same).  So if something is causing the document to not fully load, then your code would work.

Comment: I've put the code at the bottom and I still have the same problem. The first page load runs the script but the second one doesnt. The only difference between the two php files is the text language. The HTML is identical in both.

Comment: www.alkd.org.au - you will notice that when the first page loads, the english link at the top right has been modified successfully by the script. When you click on that link, you get the English page but the link hasnt changed back to the original.

Comment: My bad: The ftp upload of a page change failed for whatever reason. Once the latest version uploaded all was well.